# Google Cloud SQL Instance stuck in "Instance is being updated"

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We resized a google cloud SQL instance, and it's been stuck in the status  "Instance is being updated. This may take a few minutes" for at least two hours now.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update process as you resized your Google Cloud SQL instance. You have to create a [Support Ticket](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/) if after some hours it's still stuck.

Opening a Support Case, a SQL Specialist will cancel the updating process and your instance will be operational again.

To avoid this kind of disruptive updates any time of the day please enable the [Maintenance window](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#maintenance-window-2ndgen) so that this kind of update happens only during the Maintenance window.

Comment: What do we do if all we are is a basic user just trying this out without anything more than basic support?  I have same issue for my tiny "try it out" database.